# How to specify url from array with regex in js

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

How can detect url's from this string. Urls are in quotes that cause problem with multiple items.

```
"{"output":["www.google.com"],"screenshots":["http://10.200.200.14:5000/screenshots/id=215585/1.png","http://10.200.200.14:5000/screenshots/id=215585/2.png"]}"
```

I need to extract below:

```
http://10.244.224.44:5000/screenshots/id=215585/1.png
http://10.244.224.44:5000/screenshots/id=215585/2.png
```

Edit: I edited the line, it is actually a string and I need to extract urls to make them clickable in ace editor. So Ace editor wants me to specify a regex pattern.

```
 const CustomHighlightRules = function CustomHighlightRules() {
      let rules = new HighlightRules().getRules();
      for (const rule in rules) {
        rules[rule].unshift({
          token: ['clickables'],
          regex: /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/,
        });
```

Comment: Apparently you don't know where to start with your regex. Please check out [Reference - What does this regex mean resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618), and [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) for more info on regex.

Comment: `JSON.parse(your_string).screenshots`

Comment: I need this regex to customize ace editor styling, JSON.parse is not way I look for

Answer (score -1):

Actually you don't need Regex here:

```
var objJSON = JSON.parse('{"output":["www.google.com"],"screenshots":["http://10.200.200.14:5000/screenshots/id=215585/1.png","http://10.200.200.14:5000/screenshots/id=215585/2.png"]}');
```

Will parse the Json in obj and then:

```
document.write(obj.screenshots);
```

Use `obj.screenshots`